# Path Not Found Exception is getting when running Revit addin on server.Running successfully on local machine

Tags: autodesk-forge, revit-api, revit, autodesk-designautomation

I am working on design automation Addin for Revit 2019.Actually I have gotten stucked at one point.It is working fine when I am debugging it locally, but when I am running it through server, it gives me following response which I have attached below.Please take a look and suggest me where I can be possibly wrong.

```
[06/09/2020 10:07:33] Job information:
"CommandLine":[
  "$(engine.path)\\\\revitcoreconsole.exe /i $(args[inputFile].path) /al $(appbundles[RevisedContentAddin].path)"
]
"Settings":{
  "dasreportfailedlimits": {
    "value": "true",
    "isEnvironmentVariable": true
  }
}
"Id":"29aae4d6d5224f469560682dc901d976"
"ActivityId":"mytestapp21022020.RevisedContentAddin+test"
"Engine.Id":"Autodesk.Revit!34"
"Apps": [
"App.Id":"mytestapp21022020.RevisedContentAddin!1"
]
"BoundArguments":{
  "inputFile": {
    "localName": "$(inputFile)",
    "url": "https://content.dropboxapi.com/Masked:6GSQvBCqbc0I7MDGYfRVsnTuAfg=",
    "headers": {
      "Authorization": "Masked:O6vUSYao0e4t3D7v89SRtj616Lk=",
      "Dropbox-API-Arg": "{ \"path\":\"/adsk-forge/Test.rvt\" }"
    }
  },
  "inputZip": {
    "zip": true,
    "localName": "$(inputZip)",
    "url": "https://content.dropboxapi.com/Masked:6GSQvBCqbc0I7MDGYfRVsnTuAfg=",
    "headers": {
      "Authorization": "Masked:O6vUSYao0e4t3D7v89SRtj616Lk=",
      "Dropbox-API-Arg": "{ \"path\":\"/adsk-forge/RFA_FOLDER.zip\" }"
    }
  },
  "inputJson": {
    "localName": "params.json",
    "url": "https://content.dropboxapi.com/Masked:6GSQvBCqbc0I7MDGYfRVsnTuAfg=",
    "headers": {
      "Authorization": "Masked:O6vUSYao0e4t3D7v89SRtj616Lk=",
      "Dropbox-API-Arg": "{ \"path\":\"/adsk-forge/params.json\" }"
    }
  },
  "inputError": {
    "localName": "Error.json",
    "url": "https://content.dropboxapi.com/Masked:6GSQvBCqbc0I7MDGYfRVsnTuAfg=",
    "headers": {
      "Authorization": "Masked:O6vUSYao0e4t3D7v89SRtj616Lk=",
      "Dropbox-API-Arg": "{ \"path\":\"/adsk-forge/Error.json\" }"
    }
  },
  "outputFile": {
    "localName": "outputFile.rvt",
    "url": "https://content.dropboxapi.com/Masked:Ue5D6a5K1qggFCNLUJsXlCpkJ+E=",
    "headers": {
      "Authorization": "Masked:O6vUSYao0e4t3D7v89SRtj616Lk=",
      "Content-Type": "application/octet-stream",
      "Dropbox-API-Arg": "{\"path\":\"/adsk-forge/outputFile.rvt\", \"mode\":\"add\"}"
    },
    "verb": "post"
  },
  "outputJson": {
    "localName": "params.json",
    "url": "https://content.dropboxapi.com/Masked:Ue5D6a5K1qggFCNLUJsXlCpkJ+E=",
    "headers": {
      "Authorization": "Masked:O6vUSYao0e4t3D7v89SRtj616Lk=",
      "Content-Type": "application/octet-stream",
      "Dropbox-API-Arg": "{\"path\":\"/adsk-forge/params.json\", \"mode\":\"add\"}"
    },
    "verb": "post"
  },
  "outputError": {
    "localName": "Error.json",
    "url": "https://content.dropboxapi.com/Masked:Ue5D6a5K1qggFCNLUJsXlCpkJ+E=",
    "headers": {
      "Authorization": "Masked:O6vUSYao0e4t3D7v89SRtj616Lk=",
      "Content-Type": "application/octet-stream",
      "Dropbox-API-Arg": "{\"path\":\"/adsk-forge/Error.json\", \"mode\":\"add\"}"
    },
    "verb": "post"
  },
  "onProgress": {
    "ondemand": true,
    "url": "https://wlnr5sjl3a.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/Masked:UK/Z3b5X3xUWxXiH6C9r9i9UlRU=",
    "headers": {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      "x-das-authorize": "awssigv4(us-east-1)",
      "x-ads-token-data": "{\"access_token\":{\"client_id\":\"IxoKacMvZAUVe4Gk9vVhDWGYJI49fAGj\"},\"scope\":\"data:read data:write data:create data:search bucket:create bucket:read bucket:update bucket:delete account:read account:write code:all\",\"expires_in\":2247,\"client_id\":\"IxoKacMvZAUVe4Gk9vVhDWGYJI49fAGj\"}"
    },
    "verb": "put"
  }
}
"Quotas":{
  "limitDownloads": 200,
  "limitUploads": 200,
  "limitDownloadSizeMB": 2000,
  "limitUploadSizeMB": 2000,
  "limitProcessingTimeSec": 10800,
  "limitTotalUncompressedAppsSizeInMB": 5000
}
[06/09/2020 10:07:33] Starting work item 29aae4d6d5224f469560682dc901d976
[06/09/2020 10:07:33] Start download phase.
[06/09/2020 10:07:33] Start preparing AppPackage RevisedContentAddin.
[06/09/2020 10:07:33] Start downloading file https://content.dropboxapi.com/2/files/download.
[06/09/2020 10:07:33] Reuse previously downloaded app '0b56d13f0db62fef7a4dceaaba9f2c32.mytestapp21022020.RevisedContentAddin[1]' from local cache.
[06/09/2020 10:07:33] Start downloading file https://content.dropboxapi.com/2/files/download.
[06/09/2020 10:07:33] Start downloading file https://content.dropboxapi.com/2/files/download.
[06/09/2020 10:07:33] Start downloading file https://content.dropboxapi.com/2/files/download.
[06/09/2020 10:07:33] Error: Failed - 409 (path/not_found/...)
Request: GET https://content.dropboxapi.com/2/files/download
  Request Headers:
    Authorization: Bearer Pa0NeErce7AAAAAAAAAA2AOczAx9QihaGl48RtCHQdGlxOEOc8X8y53ntPqqcRzO
    Dropbox-API-Arg: { "path":"/adsk-forge/params.json" }
  Response Headers:
    Server: nginx
    Date: Tue, 09 Jun 2020 10:07:33 GMT
    Transfer-Encoding: chunked
    Connection: keep-alive
    Vary: Dropbox-API-Arg
    X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
    Content-Security-Policy: sandbox
    X-WebKit-CSP: sandbox
    X-Content-Security-Policy: sandbox
    X-Dropbox-Request-Id: 110f316a5fec33eccb1bbbc4dacb4753
    X-Robots-Tag: noindex, nofollow, noimageindex
  Response Content Headers:
    Content-Type: application/json
    Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=unspecified
  Response Body:
    {"error_summary": "path/not_found/...", "error": {".tag": "path", "path": {".tag": "not_found"}}}
[06/09/2020 10:07:33] Error: Unable to download file https://content.dropboxapi.com/2/files/download: System.Web.Http.HttpResponseException: Processing of the HTTP request resulted in an exception. Please see the HTTP response returned by the 'Response' property of this exception for details.
   at CoreEngineRunner.DownloadItem.HttpDownloadStreamAsync(String url, Dictionary`2 headers, IReport log, Action`1 onContentFileName, CancellationToken ct, Int64 clientTimeoutSec)
   at CoreEngineRunner.DownloadItem.DownloadAsync(TraceSource logger).
[06/09/2020 10:07:33] Error: Failed - 409 (path/not_found/...)
Request: GET https://content.dropboxapi.com/2/files/download
  Request Headers:
    Authorization: Bearer Pa0NeErce7AAAAAAAAAA2AOczAx9QihaGl48RtCHQdGlxOEOc8X8y53ntPqqcRzO
    Dropbox-API-Arg: { "path":"/adsk-forge/Error.json" }
  Response Headers:
    Server: nginx
    Date: Tue, 09 Jun 2020 10:07:33 GMT
    Transfer-Encoding: chunked
    Connection: keep-alive
    Vary: Dropbox-API-Arg
    X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
    Content-Security-Policy: sandbox
    X-WebKit-CSP: sandbox
    X-Content-Security-Policy: sandbox
    X-Dropbox-Request-Id: 70effff9759f8d429c701fef7ffe3e3c
    X-Robots-Tag: noindex, nofollow, noimageindex
  Response Content Headers:
    Content-Type: application/json
    Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=unspecified
  Response Body:
    {"error_summary": "path/not_found/...", "error": {".tag": "path", "path": {".tag": "not_found"}}}
[06/09/2020 10:07:33] Error: Unable to download file https://content.dropboxapi.com/2/files/download: System.Web.Http.HttpResponseException: Processing of the HTTP request resulted in an exception. Please see the HTTP response returned by the 'Response' property of this exception for details.
   at CoreEngineRunner.DownloadItem.HttpDownloadStreamAsync(String url, Dictionary`2 headers, IReport log, Action`1 onContentFileName, CancellationToken ct, Int64 clientTimeoutSec)
   at CoreEngineRunner.DownloadItem.DownloadAsync(TraceSource logger).
[06/09/2020 10:07:34] '352256' bytes have been written to T:\Aces\Jobs\29aae4d6d5224f469560682dc901d976\54dc126271a24adf92016eba8de1275b.rvt.
[06/09/2020 10:07:34] End downloading file https://content.dropboxapi.com/2/files/download.
[06/09/2020 10:07:38] '182077067' bytes have been written to T:\Aces\Jobs\29aae4d6d5224f469560682dc901d976\zip_1.zip.
[06/09/2020 10:07:38] End downloading file https://content.dropboxapi.com/2/files/download.
[06/09/2020 10:07:39] T:\Aces\Jobs\29aae4d6d5224f469560682dc901d976\zip_1.zip has been unpacked to folder T:\Aces\Jobs\29aae4d6d5224f469560682dc901d976\$(inputZip).
[06/09/2020 10:07:39] Error: Download failed, reason: path/not_found/... (409).
[06/09/2020 10:07:39] Error: An unexpected error happened during phase Downloading of job.
[06/09/2020 10:07:39] Job finished with result FailedDownload
[06/09/2020 10:07:39] Job Status:
{
  "status": "failedDownload",
  "reportUrl": "https://dasprod-store.s3.amazonaws.com/workItem/mytestapp21022020/29aae4d6d5224f469560682dc901d976/report.txt?AWSAccessKeyId=ASIATGVJZKM3AB4IGHG3&Expires=1591711653&x-amz-security-token=IQoJb3JpZ2luX2VjEJr%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2FwEaCXVzLWVhc3QtMSJGMEQCIALGa5UPgdrN%2BedJ9kQDj0WmtzopvtJ8pP3Vj1JzVGTaAiAuI24FSrbbm2b6aIoiv2M7NInggIh03w8HbrrxRrAEjyrVAQgSEAEaDDIyMDQ3MzE1MjMxMCIMTeYqBAUSs6Yr2CK3KrIBqyKbz5RQXfefggrtBbtzaWOHzWiYYKeS94SrYAS21YvkVaiRWjiO5oNQ5Ge%2Bj5kUD6Ebo5MWzmeGOdTvs78Pmv5wA%2Bd799bkLiBlqtHVF3xRfW5rU%2F1hFVAmMoXy%2B%2BaVm%2BMeVBskVzEgOb%2BiTl5OIuEpRxbdkh0UseiSQwiOgYiPAkGCnN%2FyCdGT%2BBIZpeI9zeJMSg57qAItA33UK%2BQDN%2FXbnQCoI8VKRie0jeTLKr3ebzCUov32BTrhAQ4G2riZ1YJOZGskxw47jFFaE4P33DoLL0Poq0r9zAZSeThOMhgor0NourIHiP%2BaUfhMYjXgnLoxxPAyb%2BWTC5TA10WCcNkROwu%2FpA6wmh2DLdMdyokzSYoj7Kt%2FSdzj%2FuuY5dqGZv9y5z4uUjKU903Zzsjg6yf4IK29hiTh8Z0gBqB9FIULzqI9LxQznkDmlphPSk%2FYkePdvT887Cn23jTj%2FYEbzBOpmDE0LEIWkDl3SnfCCAEfqvE%2B2vQPUiPIaBZH8q9xJqb94pEv5evcf6umkc3pkRiYicOPWrHCDxDHxw%3D%3D&Signature=dm6HpnFiICbCH%2BijWtZlpuA2AIE%3D",
  "stats": {
    "timeQueued": "2020-06-09T10:07:33.1476295Z",
    "timeDownloadStarted": "2020-06-09T10:07:33.3824128Z"
  },
  "id": "29aae4d6d5224f469560682dc901d976"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I wasn't aware of a "path/not_found" error on Design Automation (found at the bottom of your report) so I checked out the Dropbox API to see if it was a download problem from Dropbox.

Looks like there are many cases of "not_found" errors in the [DropBox API docs](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation), so I believe the issue lies with the Dropbox download definition.

I encourage you to re-check the definition of your input arguments to make sure there are no issues there. Let us know how it goes!

Comment: While the idea is helpful for debugging, I feel that it is not really an answer to the question, in that it does not explain the error of the original code. I think your contribution should better be done as a _comment_ instead of an _answer_.

Comment: Hi, this problem is fixed and actually the path from the dropbox was wrong from my side.